# Error while saving data in nestjs mongoose

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

I have a `post` schema:

```
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
class PostDocument extends Document {
    @Prop()
    title: string;

    @Prop({ type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' })
    categoryName: Category

}
```

And when I am trying to save the data, I am getting error:

`cast to objectid failed for value type string`

Request data:

```
title: "Test"
categoryName: "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message you've provided, it looks like you've added an `ObjectId` type to the `categoryName` field in your Mongoose schema. However, you are trying to save a string value to this field. To resolve this issue, you can either change the field type annotation to string type, or pass a valid ObjectId to the `categoryName` field.

```js
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
class PostDocument extends Document {
    @Prop()
    title: string;

    @Prop()
    categoryName: string
}

// data: { title: "Test", categoryName: "test" }
```

OR

```js
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
class PostDocument extends Document {
    @Prop()
    title: string;

    @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' })
    categoryId: Types.ObjectId

}

// data: { title: "Test", categoryId: category.id }
```

Comment: I'm not OP but offered the bounty because I have the same issue.

I have essentially the same schema that he does except:

```
  @ApiProperty()
  @Prop({type: [MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId], ref: Role.name})
  roles: Role[];
```

And this is my role:

```
export class Role extends Document {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
}
```

This structure needs to remain in tact however, when creating roles, I get an error stating cast to object id is wrong.